# Is it possible to execute code right before a field is accessed in java?

Tags: java, reflection, field

I am trying to automate the construction of some objects in java.

To do this, I have these sample classes:

```
class TestInjected extends CommonAncestor {

  TestInjected() {
    System.out.println("I am Test Injected");
  }

  void exist() {
    System.out.println("Hey there, I exist");
  }

}

class CommonAncestor {

  CommonAncestor() {
    super();
    init();
  }

  void init() {
    try {
        Field f = this.getClass().getDeclaredField("x");
        f.set(this, f.getType().newInstance());
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
    }
  }

}

public class TestInjection extends CommonAncestor{
  TestInjected x;
  private TestInjected y;

  private TestInjected getY() {
    if (y == null) {
      y = new TestInjected();
    }
    return y;
  }

  public TestInjection() {
    super();
  }

  public void test() {
    x.exist();
  }

  public void test2() {
    getY().exist();
  }

}
```

And I also have a testing class:

```
public class TestInjectionTest {

  @Test
  public void test1() {
    TestInjection t = new TestInjection();
    t.test();
    t.test2();
  }
}
```

What I am doing here is, on constructor, I check for the Field x, and I initialize it via reflection. This way, I make sure that whenever a method is called, like in this case, test(), Field x has already been initialized, and therefor, it works.

The second approach, is to force programmers to use a getter, in this case, for Field y, where this getter method makes sure to initialize the object.

However, I am wondering, if hava has any way to execute reflection, when a variable is accessed. Let's say, instead of having to execute reflection code on constructor, if somehow, that code could be executed whenever "x" is required.

i.e:

```
x.exist()
```

--> check x is getting called, initialize it, **and then** call exist()

Any reflection method, or any library, that gives me this?

Comment: It seems that you are trying to achieve the wrong thing. Unfortunately I don't know yet what is your real concern. In other words: What is the real problem you want to solve. What you are doing is one of the worst things I've ever seen in Java.

Comment: Could you give a real world example on what you want to achieve. It feels like you're overthinking a very simple issue. Also, this reminds of the XY-problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: This is just a very simple case, did not want to explain the whole problem. In summary, I am trying to have different interlinked objects, referencing between themselves. I do not want to have all programmers being extremely carefull on how this objects are constructed first, in order to avoid more than 1 instance for each object... It's more complicated than this little example, let's say

Answer (score 1):

I can't really understand what problem you are trying to solve, but I'm sure there is a better solution. Work with the platform, not against it. Having said that the answer is no in the general case. You could run something that rewrites the byte codes (essentially adding a getter behind the scenes) but you can't intercept field accesses out of the box.

Make the fields private and expose them with methods if you need to initialize them. Or do it in the constructor.

EDIT: based on your comments I think what you are really looking for is dependency injection. Take a look at CDI (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giwhl.html) or Spring (https://spring.io) or Guice (https://github.com/google/guice).